# How to force Xamarin Forms ListView to redraw/resize overlapping labels when HasUnevenRows = true

Tags: image, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, cell

I have a Page with a listview that has a contentview as a viewcell.  The contentview has an image (in fact is a cachedimage object).  The listview has uneven rows to accommodate various image heights.

Unfortunately the objects like labels, etc., overlap from each of the rows after the images within those rows have loaded.  I've read that I should be using 'ForceUpdateSize' but I'm not sure where in the code to place this (or even if it will work).

(On a side note, there is no ovelap when my contentview (viewcell) has a grid with starred heights but this leads to lots of unnecessary gaps between rows).

P.s. It's a contentview as I'm using re-using this XAML and code in Xamarin pages without a listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myapp" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="myapp.HomePage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <local:MyContentView x:Name="MyContentView">
                    </local:MyContentView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="myapp.MyContentView">
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,1">
            <Button Text="username" x:Name="UsernameBtn" Clicked="Username_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="follow" x:Name="FollowBtn" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="Follow_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="..." x:Name="MoreBtn" Clicked="More_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="Image" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" DownsampleToViewSize="true" Source="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
            <Button Text="Like" x:Name="LikeBtn" Clicked="Like_Clicked" Image="http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bookmark-icon-2-614x460.png" />
            <Button Text="Comment" x:Name="CommentBtn" Clicked="Comment_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Share" x:Name="ShareBtn" Clicked="Share_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Bkmrk" x:Name="BookMarkPostBtn" Clicked="BookmarkPost_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Image="http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bookmark-icon-2-614x460.png" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
            <Label x:Name="LikeCount" Text="1,234" />
            <Label Text="Likes" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="CommentLabel" Text="Comments" />
        <Label x:Name="TagLabel" Text="Tags" />
    </StackLayout>

    <!--
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="5" RowSpacing="5" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Button Text="username" x:Name="UsernameBtn" Clicked="Username_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="follow" x:Name="FollowBtn" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="Follow_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="..." x:Name="MoreBtn" Clicked="More_Clicked" />

        </StackLayout>

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="Image" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" DownsampleToViewSize="true" Source="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>


        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
            <Button Text="Like" x:Name="LikeBtn" Clicked="Like_Clicked" Image="http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bookmark-icon-2-614x460.png" />
            <Button Text="Comment" x:Name="CommentBtn" Clicked="Comment_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Share" x:Name="ShareBtn" Clicked="Share_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Bkmrk" x:Name="BookMarkPostBtn" Clicked="BookmarkPost_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Image="http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bookmark-icon-2-614x460.png" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
            <Label x:Name="LikeCount" Text="1,234" />
            <Label Text="Likes" />
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="CommentLabel" Text="Comments" />
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="TagLabel" Text="Tags" />


    </Grid>
    -->

</ContentView.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that inherits from ViewCell and use that instead of ViewCell in your ItemTemplate. Inside this class is where you will call ForceUpdateSize().

However this might not be your actual problem if the Grid seems to work, although there is extra spacing. You should probably avoid * height in your Grid inside ListView, and instead use Auto or pixel heights.

Comment: Tried suggestion.  Auto creates overlaps. Star creates lots of space. ForceUpdateSize is repeatedly called and slows down UI. I have a workaround where I set the fontsize and this reduces number of visual overlaps but not elminates them.  Isn't there a robust way of creating uneven height rows of listview in Xamarin without the cells collapsing on each other once they've been populated?....I'll keep hacking away for time being